# How To resolve Syntax Error when using SQL Insert Into Select MySQL

Tags: mysql

I Have problem when using INSERT INTO SELECT function on mysql database, error is like this

```
the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tmpProgkeg SELECT A.Tahun, 1, A.Kd_Urusan, A.Kd_Bidang, A.Kd_Un' at line 4
```

this Is Mysql Query

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tfVhWXC25EAQKHdpHv6VLU/0

i need help, thanks before...

Answer (score 2):

Note that before your INSERT statement, you have a CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpProgkeg (
...
) 
INSERT INTO tmpProgkeg SELECT ...
```

But you don't terminate the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statement with the required semicolon (`;`) character.

Each SQL statement must be terminated. For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpProgkeg (
...
);
INSERT INTO tmpProgkeg SELECT ...
```

The requirement to terminate statements is similar to some other programming languages, for example C++, Java, or PHP.

Tip: When MySQL reports syntax errors, it shows you some portion of an SQL statement. It's telling you "I didn't expect the following code at the position you used it." It got confused because it was expecting some other code, the end of code, and it's showing you what it saw instead, *following* the point where it got confused.

So when you see

> the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO ...

You know that you should look at your code *right before that point*, to see what you forgot.